# Setting TypeFace NullpointerException

Tags: android, typeface

I want to add a `TypeFace` to my `TextView`. here's my Java code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView helptitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_help);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "beyond_the_mountains.ttf");
        helptitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
}
```

but when i run the app, i get a log cat error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.enxin.crystallise.Help.onCreate(Help.java:15)
```

There are many kinds of NullPointerException so I'm not sure how to solve this

Comment: first make call  setContentView(R.layout.activity_help); then findViewById. btw where did you put fonts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `findViewById()` before setting the content view.

`findViewById()` implicitly calls `getWindow()` which is still `null` at that time.

Call `setContentView()` **before** initializing your `View`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

    TextView helptitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_help);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "beyond_the_mountains.ttf");
    helptitle.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 //You have mistaken the order
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);    
 TextView helptitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_help);
 Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),    "beyond_the_mountains.ttf");
 helptitle.setTypeface(typeface);
```